# Different types of Shallow copy [SOLVED: aliasing vs copying]

Tags: java, shallow-copy

This question is not about explaining how shallow/deep work, but examples of shallow copy.

I am making notes, and I wonder if these two examples both 'fall under the roof' of shallow copies. Yes, they are a little different, but are they both so called 'shallow copies'? Code:

```
ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
colors.add("Red");
colors.add("Blue");

ArrayList<String> shallowOne = new ArrayList<>(colors);
ArrayList<String> shallowTwo = colors;
```

ShallowOne has reference to elements **inside** object colors.

ShallowTwo has direct reference to object colors.

So, are they both using famous concept of Shallow copy? Or..terminology is different for them?

Comment: I don't think I would personally refer to the second kind as a shallow copy. I don't think any copy actually has actually occurred. It's calling aliasing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just googled it. Thanks. For anyone who might reach this, check this out http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~sibel/csci1100/fall2015/course_notes/exam2_review/aliasing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example you've given is not an example of shallow copying. In fact, no copy has occurred: this is called aliasing.

There are some languages, however, where this isn't necessarily true. In Rust, for instance, a shallow/deep copy is made on assignment if the datatype has been marked as `Copy`, and a move assignment happens otherwise (where the old name is no longer usable, so no aliasing happens here either).